# How can I enable readline for PHP 5.4 on Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: ubuntu, php, readline

I installed PHP 5.4 on my Ubuntu 11.10 PC like this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install php5
```

It's working fine but I don't have the `readline` function anymore that I need for my PHP CLI scripts. `libreadline-dev` is installed and `readline` was working perfectly in 5.3.

I also tried to compile 5.4 with readline:

```
$ wget http://de2.php.net/get/php-5.4.0.tar.gz/from/de.php.net/mirror
$ tar xzvf mirror
$ cd php-5.4.0/
$ ./configure --with-readline
$ make test
```

But the last command echoed this error after compiling for some minutes:

> FAILED TEST SUMMARY
>   Test 7: DTD tests [ext/dom/tests/dom007.phpt] 
>   You may have found a problem in PHP.

I appreciate any help on how to get `readline` working!

Comment: Oh no! Please consider reporting this bug to the PHP team. http://php.net/mailing-lists.php

Comment: PHP regularly has broken tests, you may want to build without running them. Also, if the PPA repo has source packages, you may want to get them and start from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
$ cd php-5.4.0/ext/readline
$ phpize && ./configure && make
```

Then you will end up with a modules/readline.so which can be loaded from php.ini (`make install` will move it to extension_dir).

Answer (score 1):

Use dotdeb. It's like 1 minute work.

1. Add the main repository to your sources.list

   Depending on your distribution (Wheezy or Squeeze), add these two lines to your /etc/apt/sources.list file (you can also choose a mirror near you) :

   ```
   deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all  
   deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
   ```

   or

   ```
   deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all  
   deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
   ```
2. Fetch and install the GnuPG key.

   ```
   wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
   sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
   ```
3. Run `apt-get update`. You should now be able to install the Dotdeb packages you want with apt-get (or dselect, or aptitude as well…)

and then `sudo apt-get install php5-readline`

<sub>**Source:** https://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/</sub>

Comment: Hi bob, welcome to Super User! Can you [edit] your answer to include the essential information from the link? We do not like URL-only answers. Thanks!

Comment: Ubuntu 11.10 is an End of Life release, but in Ubuntu 14.04 php5-readline can be installed from the default Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this, worked for me (Debian):

```
apt-get install php5-readline
```